# Simple Triangle-like Inequality for a general norm

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, convex-geometry, triangle-inequality

I came up with this inequality as I was thinking about norms. I don't know if it's true though.

Given three points $x,y,z$ in a normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, is it true that if

$$
\|x-y\|\le\|y\|
$$

and

$$
\|x-z\|\le\|z\|
$$

then

$$
\|x-(y+z)\|\le\|y+z\| ?
$$

In other words, for a given vector $x$ in a normed space $X$, is the set $K:=\{y:\|x-y\|\le\|y\|\}$ additive?

First, if it were true, it almost looks like we could change the $y$ and $z$ around so that, e.g. the 1st and 3rd inequalities imply the 2nd. As it is, given any arrangement $x+y=z$ (none of which is $0$), we can tell which is which by simply adding.

I thought proving $X=\mathbb{R}$ would easily turn into $X=l_p$, but that seems naive.

## Inner Product Space

The first two inequalities reduce to

$$
\langle x,x\rangle\le 2\langle y,x\rangle
$$

and

$$
\langle x,x\rangle\le 2\langle z,x\rangle
$$

Adding these together gets

$$
\|x\|^2\le \langle y+z,x\rangle\le 2\langle y+z,x\rangle
$$

Working the same algebra backwards then gets the third inequality.

## Other norms?

Note that if $y\in K$, then $cy\in K$ for all $c\ge 1$. So there is a curve/surface in $X$, symmetric about $0$ (AKA odd), that divides $X$ into two parts, one part being $K$. It looks like if the unit ball $B$ of $X$ is oblong and $x$ is not perpendicular to an axis of symmetry of B, the curve/surface will not be linear and hence not convex (symmetric about $0$ and convex implies linear).

So, the factor of $2$ cannot be dismissed for general $X$ as it was for inner product spaces (?). I feel like that argument says the 2 cannot be dismissed for some inner product spaces as well. Mistake?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Your claim of "First, if it were true," is not valid. You need it to hold true for the difference, and not for the sum.

Comment: If you want the statement to hold for all $x, y, z$, then that is not possible (E.g take $ y = 0, x \neq 0 $.) If $x$ is fixed, then the statement is true (as you have shown).

Comment: Thanks, Calvin. Yes, I'm thinking of $x,y,z$ as fixed

Answer (score 3):

The inequality can fail for $X=\Bbb R^2$ endowed with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. Indeed, let $x=(1,0)$, $y=(-1,2)$, and $z=(-1,-2)$. Then $\|x-y\|=\|y\|=\|x-z\|=\|z\|=2$, but $\|x-(y+z)\|=3>2=\|y+z\|$.

Comment: Hmm, not bad, thanks!

Any ideas on characterizing which norms the inequality holds?

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith Yes. I have a very naive idea to try derive the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law) 
from the inequality.

Comment: Actually, this is only part of an attempt to prove that for any finite set $S$ in a NLS, where $\Sigma(S)$ represents their sum, that there is some $s\inS$ satisfying $\|s-\Sigma(S)\|\ge \|s\|$

Comment: So this is a counterexample to my “original” problem as well

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith Which $S$ you take for the counterexample?

Comment: Any $x,y,z$ so that $\|x-?\|\le\|?\|$ for $?=y,z$ but $\|x-(y+z)\|>\|y+z\|$ will cause the $S=\{y,z,x-(y+z)\}$

Comment: @AlexRavsky Would you be willing to share your idea for deriving the parallelogram law from this? Even if not fully formed, I would still be very interested!

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith In your example $\Sigma(S)=x$ so if $\|y\|=\|x-y\|$ (as in my example) then we can pick $s=y$.

Comment: @NikhilSahoo I don’t know how to derive the parallelogram law from this. It was only a conjecture that this can be done. I think a point to this problem is to investigate the geometrical properties of the unit ball in (at most) three-dimensional subspace of $X$ containing $x$, $y$, and $z$. I think a good point to start is  $X=\Bbb R^2$ endowed with some norm.

Comment: @NikhilSahoo Thanks. I got caught up in a version of the original problem and did not reconcile correctly. So maybe the original is true.....

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith I think I figured it out! I'm busy right now, but I'll post a proof (modulo one reference) that your property characterizes Euclidean norms, sometime later today.

Comment: Hmmm, I await your reply! Do you think it's true in general NLS that for any finite set $S$ in a NLS, where $\Sigma(S)$ represents their sum, that there is some $s\in S$ satisfying $\|s-\Sigma(S)\|\ge\|s\|$?

Comment: Updated! Let me know what you think. :)

Answer (score 2):

We wish to investigate the statement
$$
\|y-x\|\le\|y\|\land\|z-x\|\le\|z\|\implies\|y+z-x\|\le\|y+z\|\tag0
$$

---

**Inner Product Spaces**

Suppose that we are in an inner product space: $|u|^2=\langle u,u\rangle$.

**Proposition 1:**
$$
|y-x|\le|y-o|\land|z-x|\le|z-o|\implies\left|\frac{y+z}2-x\,\right|\le\left|\frac{y+z}2-o\,\right|\tag1
$$
**Proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{y+z}2-o\,\right|^2-\left|\frac{y+z}2-x\,\right|^2\\[6pt]
&=\langle(y+z)-(x+o),x-o\rangle\tag{2a}\\[6pt]
&=\left\langle y-\frac{o+x}2,x-o\right\rangle+\left\langle z-\frac{x+o}2,x-o\right\rangle\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac12\left(|y-o|^2-|y-x|^2\right)+\frac12\left(|z-o|^2-|z-x|^2\right)\tag{2c}\\[6pt]
&\ge0\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: $\langle u+v,u-v\rangle=|u|^2-|v|^2$
$\text{(2b)}$: linearity of the inner product
$\text{(2c)}$: $\langle u+v,u-v\rangle=|u|^2-|v|^2$
$\text{(2d)}$: assumptions

$\large\square$

---

**Proposition 2:**
$$
|p-x|\le|p-o|\implies\left|p-\frac{x+o}2\,\right|\le|p-o|\tag3
$$
**Proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
\left|p-\frac{x+o}2\,\right|^2
&=\left\langle p-\frac{x+o}2,p-\frac{x+o}2\right\rangle\tag{4a}\\
&=\left\langle\frac{p-x}2+\frac{p-o}2,\frac{p-x}2+\frac{p-o}2\right\rangle\tag{4b}\\
&=\frac14\langle p-x,p-x\rangle+\frac12\langle p-x,p-o\rangle+\frac14\langle p-o,p-o\rangle\tag{4c}\\
&\le\frac14|p-x|^2+\frac12|p-x||p-o|+\frac14|p-o|^2\tag{4d}\\[4pt]
&\le|p-o|^2\tag{4e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: write norm in terms of inner product
$\text{(4b)}$: rewrite the terms in the inner product
$\text{(4c)}$: use the linearity of the inner product
$\text{(4d)}$: $\langle u,v\rangle\le|u||v|$
$\text{(4e)}$: $|x-p|\le|o-p|$

$\large\square$

---

**Statement $\textbf{(0)}$ Holds in an Inner Product Space**

In general, a counterexample is hard to visualize because Statement $(0)$ is true in an inner product space:
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\color{#090}{|y-x|\le|y-o|}}^{|y-x|\le|y|}\land\overbrace{\color{#00F}{|z-x|\le|z-o|}}^{|z-x|\le|z|}
&\implies\left|\frac{y+z}2-x\,\right|\le\left|\frac{y+z}2-o\,\right|\tag{5a}\\
&\implies\underbrace{\color{#C00}{\left|\frac{y+z}2-\frac{x+o}2\,\right|\le\left|\frac{y+z}2-o\right|}}_{|y+z-x|\le|y+z|}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: Proposition 1
$\text{(5b)}$: Proposition 2 with $p=\frac{y+z}2$

---

**Importance of Convexity**

[image]

Proposition 1 says that the region which is closer to $x$ than to $o$ (the origin) is convex. Since $y$ and $z$ are in that region (to the right of the vertical black line), so is $\frac{y+z}2$.

Proposition 2 says that any point that is closer to $x$ than to $o$ is closer to $\frac{x+o}2$ than to $o$. That is, the region to the right of the vertical black line is also to the right of the vertical violet line, and anything to the right of the vertical violet line is closer to $\frac{x+o}2$ than to $o$.

---

**Other Norms**

For inner product spaces, convexity plays an important part in proving Statement $(0)$. Using the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm,
$$
\|(x,y)\|_\infty=\max(|x|,|y|)\tag6
$$
the region where $\|p-x\|\le\|p\|$ need not be convex, and the statement fails.

[image]

The violet region is where $\|p-x\|\le\|p\|$ and the green region is where $\|p-x/2\|\gt\|p\|$. Since $y$ and $z$ are in the violet region, we have
$$
\|y-x\|\le\|y\|\land\|z-x\|\le\|z\|\tag7
$$
However, since $\frac{y+z}2=(0,0)$ is in the green region, we have
$$
\|y+z-x\|\gt\|y+z\|\tag8
$$
Inequalities $(7)$ and $(8)$ show that $(0)$ fails.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Total rewrite! … And then partial retraction. Hopefully, some part of this is still helpful and I will continue to think about how to get a possibly complete answer.** This is a great question. I've spent quite a while thinking about it now, as well as perusing Dan Amir's [*Characterizations of Inner Product Spaces*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783034854894) for possibly related conditions. I thought I had a solution, but I made a sign error that you (Aaron Goldsmith) pointed out.

First, some definitions. Let $(V,||\cdot||)$ be a normed vector space. For any $x\in V$, define
$$K_x=\big\{y\in V:||x-y||\leq ||y||\big\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad J_x=\big\{y\in V:||x-y||\leq ||x+y||\big\}.$$
For any $x\in V$, notice that $K_{2x}=x+J_x$ and thus $\partial K_{2x}=x+\partial J_x$. Note also that $$\partial J_x=\big\{y\in V:||x-y||=||x+y||\big\}=J_x\cap J_{-x},$$ for any $x\neq 0$.
Now, I can state my partial result.

**Proposition.** Consider the following conditions:

1. $||\cdot||$ arises from an inner product on $V$;
2. $J_x$ is convex for all $x\in V$;
3. $\partial J_x$ is convex for all $x\in V$;
4. $J_x$ is additive for all $x\in V$;
5. $\partial J_x$ is additive for all $x\in V$;
6. $K_x$ is convex for all $x\in V$;
7. $\partial K_x$ is convex for all $x\in V$;
8. $K_x$ is additive for all $x\in V$.

I conjecture that $(8) \Longrightarrow (1)$, but have yet to prove it. We do know that $$(1)\Longleftrightarrow(2) \Longleftrightarrow (3) \Longleftrightarrow (4) \Longleftrightarrow (5) \Longleftrightarrow (6) \Longleftrightarrow (7) \Longrightarrow (8).$$

*Proof.* The equivalences $(1)\Longleftrightarrow (3)$ and $(1)\Longleftrightarrow(5)$ are conditions $(3.2)$ and $(4.13)$ in Amir's book, respectively. Since convexity is preserved by translation, we also have $(2)\Longleftrightarrow(6)$ and $(3)\Longleftrightarrow(7).$ To complete the proof, we will show that $(2)\Longrightarrow (3)$ and $(4)\Longrightarrow (5)$, and that $(1)\Longrightarrow (2),$ $(4)$, $(6)$ and $(8)$.

$(2)\Longrightarrow (3)$ and $(4)\Longrightarrow (5)$: Suppose that $J_x$ is convex (resp. additive) for all $x\in V$. First note that $\partial J_0=\partial V=\emptyset$ is vacuously convex and additive. If $x\neq 0$, then $\partial J_x=J_x\cap J_{-x}$ is convex (resp. additive) because convex (resp. additive) sets are closed under intersection.

$(1)\Longrightarrow (2)$, $(4)$, $(6)$ and $(8)$: Suppose that $||x||^2=\langle x,x\rangle$ for all $x\in V$, where $\langle \,\cdot\,,\cdot\,\rangle$ is an inner product on $V$. Then we have $$J_x=\big\{y\in V:\langle x,y\rangle \geq 0\big\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad K_x=\big\{y\in V:2\langle x,y\rangle \geq ||x||^2\big\}.$$ These sets are both convex and additive, since they are inverse images of sets that are convex and additive under the linear map $y\mapsto \langle x,y\rangle$. $\square$

The proof of $(8)\Longrightarrow (1)$ still eludes me at this time, though I thought for a minute that I had figured it out. It’s more difficult because additivity is *not* preserved by translation, unlike convexity. For another instance of this, we could consider the condition “$\partial K_x$ is additive for all $x\in V$.” This is never true when $\dim V>0$, because if $x\neq 0$, then $x\in\partial K_{2x}$, but $2x$ is in the interior of $K_{2x}$.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil! This book is very relevant. There's also a more recent book by Alsina, Sakorska, Tomas titled

Norm Derivatives and Characterizations of Inner Product Spaces

Comment: Looks OK. A good job!

Comment: Wow, thanks for all your time. Your list of equivalencies is a powerful tool to work around these matters. That was fun. I’m going to look into these books next year. Unfortunately, I have delayed too much study for my actuary exam.

Comment: I think you have a sign error. That is, $0\not\in K_{2x}$, but $x\in J_x$ hence $0\in J_x-x$. I believe it is $K_{2x}=J_x+x$

Comment: So, I have a problem with $(6)\Rightarrow (2)$. Subtraction is not  necessarily closed under an additive set.

Comment: Yes, you’re absolutely right! I didn’t use subtraction there, but I did use $K_{2x}=J_x-x$, which (as you said) is wrong. I’ll think about how (or if) it can be corrected.

Comment: I didnt even realize at first that I still needed to center the "James bisector" but I believe I am on my way to proving the so-called original problem for a general norm. Sounds like such properties are hard to come by! I'm still interested in your resolution. Let's reconvene when we have it all figured out. Thanks!